# Rviz get selected markers

Tags: ros, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've written an Rviz plugin that allows users to click on interactive markers to label them. There are typically many markers in a scene that share a label, so I'd like to be able to label groups of markers at once. I can select groups of markers using the selection tool, but I can't figure out how to get a list of selected markers from my within my plugin. Does anyone know how to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56653/rviz-get-selected-markers/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use VisualizationManager::getSelectionManager, SelectionManager::getSelection and SelectionManager::getHandler.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-03-01**:
Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

**Comment by [pBartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/9141/pbartels/) on 2013-11-25**:
Hello,

I'm not sure about labeling but we wrote a plugin that publishes all selected points on a ros topic. Perhaps a look at the code would be helpful:
https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg/tree/master/rviz-plugin-selected-points-topic

Best, phil